# how to identify button element is focused

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

```
<div class="text-right">
  <th-input-group [(ngModel)]="filter" (keyup)="onInput($event, false, true)" 
       id="filterInput" #filterInput 
       [placeholder]="searchFilterPlaceHolder"></th-input-group>

   <th-button id="btnPopClose" #btnPopClose type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
   (click)="onFavPopupClose()">{{closeButtonText}}
   </th-button>
</div>
```

I have above html input and button element in my custom popup modal.

not in component I am using HostListener to identify tab key press.

```
@ViewChild('filterInput') elementfilterInputRef: any;
@ViewChild('btnPopClose') elementCloseButtonRef: any;

@HostListener('keydown.tab')
onTab() {
if(this.elementCloseButtonRef.hasFocued || 
this.elementfilterInputRef.hasfocued){
this.close();
}
}
```

I am trying to navigate the popup using tab .where I want to check if both the element doesn't have focus then close the popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `focus` and `blur` events like

```
<th-button id="btnPopClose" #btnPopClose type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
   (click)="onFavPopupClose()"
   (focus)="isBtnPopCloseFocused = true" 
   (blur)="isBtnPopCloseFocused = false">{{closeButtonText}}
</th-button>
```